# How do I provide credentials from CloudFoundry to AWS-sdk

Tags: cloud-foundry, aws-sdk-js

I'm learning CloudFoundry, and trying to get my node.js app to access my AWS S3 service. I've bound my AWS S3 service to the app (in `manifest.yml`, path `applications/services`). In code, I can get the credentials using [cfenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv), but how do I supply them to AWS?

```
var cfenv = require("cfenv");
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();
var my_s3_service = appEnv.getService('my-s3-service');
/* my_s3_service.credentials = {
        "api_key": "(redacted)",
        "bucket": "(redacted)",
        "endpoint": "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
        "location_constraint": "eu-west-1",
        "secret_key": "(redacted)",
        "uri": "s3://(redacted):(redacted)@s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/(redacted)"
    }

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update(Uhhh... something with my_s3_service.credentials... but what?);

const s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.getObject({
        Bucket: my_s3_service.credentials,
        Key: "my-key.json"
    }, (...));
```

Looking in [AWS SDK for JavaScript - Setting Credentials in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html), I see several methods to provide credentials - but none starts with the credentials object I have...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var servicekey = my_s3_service.credentials;
var creds = new AWS.Credentials(servicekey.api_key, servicekey.secret_key);
AWS.config.update({credentials: creds});
```

How I found out: I debugged how it worked locally, and saw that `AWS.config.credentials` was of type `SharedIniFileCredentials`, taken locally from `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials` [(ref)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html), which presumably was instated when I configured AWS cli. So I guessed I needed to put an [AWS.Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html) object in there